# Facebook SDK v4 and Graph Api 2.x auto post in Fan Page Wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a Facebook SDK 4 and Graph Api 2.x for auto post in my Facebook Fan Page. My problem is that the post is published correctly and the post's configuration appears in Fan Page Wall as public but I'm the only person who can see it.

The scopes for my access token are: publish_pages, manage_pages, publish_actions.

And the used code is:

```
require_once("Facebook/autoload.php"); //Facebook SDK v4
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'Facebook/src/Facebook/');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;


$APP_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //app id
$APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //app secret
//token
$TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //access token
$ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // facebook page id

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($APP_ID, $APP_SECRET);

$session_facebook = new FacebookSession($TOKEN);

$params = array(
  "message" => 'Message',
  "link" => "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.url",
  "picture" => "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.url/images/image.jpg",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.test-url.url",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK."
);
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session_facebook, 'POST', '/'.$ID.'/feed', $params))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance
Sergio

Comment: why do you need publish_actions?

Comment: Hi, luschn. I just wont that my webpage auto post publish in my fan page wall. Don't I need this permission?

Comment: no, you only need manage_pages and publish_pages if you want to post "as page"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works and you are the only user who can see it, most likely you forgot to set your App live. In your App settings, go to "Status & Review" and make sure that checkbox on top is set to "YES". It´s right next to this text:

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

Comment: Oooohhhhhhh!! You're right luschn. My app is in development mode now. I think it was the problem. I am going to try it. Thanks for all.

Comment: Is it necessary to have my app publish for auto post in my facebook wall? I just wont it.

Comment: not sure what you mean. of course it has to be live.